# Monitoring tasks not working with django-celery, rabbitmq on virtualenv

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I trying to make a work django with django-cellery, I created my project on virtualenv and I used template https://github.com/xenith/django-base-template and followings:

```
Django==1.6.5
celery==3.1.11
django-celery==3.1.10
```

My celery settings in settings/local.py

```
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://django:pas****@10.0.1.17:5672/myvhost'
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = 'djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend'
CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True
```

I have one Periodic Task "Update_All_Feeds" when I start "celery beat", it seems that everything working fine, task is executed every 10sec.

python manage.py celery beat

```
celery beat v3.1.11 (Cipater) is starting.
__    -    ... __   -        _
Configuration ->
    . broker -> amqp://django@10.0.1.17:5672/myvhost
    . loader -> djcelery.loaders.DjangoLoader
    . scheduler -> djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler

    . logfile -> [stderr]@%INFO
    . maxinterval -> now (0s)
[2014-05-31 20:53:16,544: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting...
[2014-05-31 20:53:16,544: INFO/MainProcess] Writing entries...
[2014-05-31 20:53:16,669: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task Update_All_ Feeds (update_all_feeds)
[2014-05-31 20:53:19,031: WARNING/MainProcess] /home/phosting/python/django/polskifeed/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:903: RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField FeedItem.pub_date received a naive datetime (2014-05-31 19:21:49) while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning)

[2014-05-31 20:53:19,081: INFO/MainProcess] Writing entries...
[2014-05-31 20:53:26,675: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task Update_All_ Feeds (update_all_feeds)
[2014-05-31 20:53:36,682: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task Update_All_ Feeds (update_all_feeds)
[2014-05-31 20:53:46,688: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task Update_All_ Feeds (update_all_feeds)
[2014-05-31 20:53:56,695: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task Update_All_ Feeds (update_all_feeds)
```

But starting this with `celeryd` is not doing anything

python manage.py celeryd -l DEBUG

```
-------------- celery@czterykaty v3.1.11 (Cipater)
---- **** ----- 
--- * ***  * -- Linux-2.6.32-bpo.5-xen-amd64-x86_64-with-debian-7.0
-- * - **** --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         default:0x13bb510 (djcelery.loaders.DjangoLoader)
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://django@10.0.1.17:5672/myvhost
- ** ---------- .> results:     djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 4 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- 
--- ***** ----- [queues]
 -------------- .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
                

[tasks]
  . celery.backend_cleanup
  . celery.chain
  . celery.chord
  . celery.chord_unlock
  . celery.chunks
  . celery.group
  . celery.map
  . celery.starmap
  . update_all_feeds
  . update_feeds

[2014-05-31 20:58:55,353: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Starting Hub
[2014-05-31 20:58:55,354: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2014-05-31 20:58:55,354: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Starting Pool
[2014-05-31 20:58:55,672: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2014-05-31 20:58:55,675: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Starting Consumer
[2014-05-31 20:58:55,676: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Connection
[2014-05-31 20:58:55,739: DEBUG/MainProcess] Start from server, version: 0.9, properties: {u'information': u'Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/', u'product': u'RabbitMQ', u'copyright': u'Copyright (C) 2007-2014 GoPivotal, Inc.', u'capabilities': {u'exchange_exchange_bindings': True, u'connection.blocked': True, u'authentication_failure_close': True, u'basic.nack': True, u'per_consumer_qos': True, u'consumer_priorities': True, u'consumer_cancel_notify': True, u'publisher_confirms': True}, u'cluster_name': u'rabbit@czterykaty.luser.nl', u'platform': u'Erlang/OTP', u'version': u'3.3.1'}, mechanisms: [u'PLAIN', u'AMQPLAIN'], locales: [u'en_US']
[2014-05-31 20:58:55,741: DEBUG/MainProcess] Open OK!
[2014-05-31 20:58:55,744: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://django@10.0.1.17:5672/myvhost
[2014-05-31 20:58:55,744: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2014-05-31 20:58:55,744: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Events
[2014-05-31 20:58:55,791: DEBUG/MainProcess] Start from server, version: 0.9, properties: {u'information': u'Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/', u'product': u'RabbitMQ', u'copyright': u'Copyright (C) 2007-2014 GoPivotal, Inc.', u'capabilities': {u'exchange_exchange_bindings': True, u'connection.blocked': True, u'authentication_failure_close': True, u'basic.nack': True, u'per_consumer_qos': True, u'consumer_priorities': True, u'consumer_cancel_notify': True, u'publisher_confirms': True}, u'cluster_name': u'rabbit@czterykaty.luser.nl', u'platform': u'Erlang/OTP', u'version': u'3.3.1'}, mechanisms: [u'PLAIN', u'AMQPLAIN'], locales: [u'en_US']
[2014-05-31 20:58:55,795: DEBUG/MainProcess] Open OK!
[2014-05-31 20:58:55,797: DEBUG/MainProcess] using channel_id: 1
[2014-05-31 20:58:55,800: DEBUG/MainProcess] Channel open
[2014-05-31 20:58:55,802: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2014-05-31 20:58:55,802: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Mingle
[2014-05-31 20:58:55,803: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2014-05-31 20:58:55,805: DEBUG/MainProcess] using channel_id: 1
[2014-05-31 20:58:55,807: DEBUG/MainProcess] Channel open
[2014-05-31 20:58:57,266: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2014-05-31 20:58:57,266: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2014-05-31 20:58:57,267: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Gossip
[2014-05-31 20:58:57,268: DEBUG/MainProcess] using channel_id: 2
[2014-05-31 20:58:57,270: DEBUG/MainProcess] Channel open
[2014-05-31 20:58:57,282: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2014-05-31 20:58:57,282: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Heart
[2014-05-31 20:58:57,285: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2014-05-31 20:58:57,286: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Tasks
[2014-05-31 20:58:57,299: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2014-05-31 20:58:57,299: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Control
[2014-05-31 20:58:57,300: DEBUG/MainProcess] using channel_id: 3
[2014-05-31 20:58:57,303: DEBUG/MainProcess] Channel open
[2014-05-31 20:58:57,311: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2014-05-31 20:58:57,311: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting event loop

[2014-05-31 20:58:57,315: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@czterykaty ready.
[2014-05-31 20:58:57,316: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Hub.register Pool...
[2014-05-31 20:58:57,317: DEBUG/MainProcess] basic.qos: prefetch_count->16
```

Periodic tasks are setup trough djcelery/admin interface, and also tasks list are empty This is my first experience with celery, and djano-celery, so I not sure what is wrong.

Comment: Please try to change the title to sometjing describing the actual problem instead of simply replicating the tags. You have a question? Fine, just ask it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed this working.
I adjusted my settings in settings/local.py with followings:

```
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://django:django123@10.0.1.17:5672/myvhost'
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = 'djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'
```

Started celeryd with flag -E and -B

```
python manage.py celeryd -l INFO -E -B
```

And for monitoring events, was necessary to start celerycam

```
python manage.py celerycam
```